# The repository sonar-pkg does not have a Release file

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

On Ubuntu 16.04 I added the following line to `/etc/apt/source.list`:

```
deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sonar-pkg/deb binary/
```

Then I run `sudo apt-get update`. The following warning shows up:

```
W: The repository 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sonar-pkg/deb binary/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is there a way to pass a authentication for the [`sonar` packages](https://sonarqube.org) to apt?

Comment: The repo maintainer should add the `Release` file. See: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#A.22Release.22_files

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem

When you run `sudo apt install sonar` you will see this message:

`Install these packages without verification? [y/N]`

Just press <kbd>y</kbd> and `sonar` will be installed :)

Comment: I did that already. Still I want to resolve the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Have just faced the same problem: Ubuntu 17.10 Artful:

```
E: The repository 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sonar-pkg/deb binary/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Temporary solution is to [download the Debian package](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sonar-pkg/deb) and install it like:

```
dpkg -i sonar_6.7.1_all.deb
```